# Hello.js example showing an error

Tags: javascript, hello.js

I almost copy/pasted this example from the Hello.js website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/hello/hello.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
hello.init({ 
    facebook : XXXXXXXXXXX, //Plz note that I replaced a correct ID with the XXXXXXXXXX
},{redirect_uri:'redirect.html'});

hello.on('auth.login', function(auth){

    // call user information, for the given network
    hello( auth.network ).api( '/me' ).then( function(r){
        // Inject it into the container
        var label = document.getElementById( "profile_"+ auth.network );
        if(!label){
            label = document.createElement('div');
            label.id = "profile_"+auth.network;
            document.getElementById('profile').appendChild(label);
        }
        label.innerHTML = '<img src="'+ r.thumbnail +'" /> Hey '+r.name;
    });
});
</script>
<button onclick="hello('facebook').login()">Facebook</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click the facebook login button the console always shows me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response_type' of undefined

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited it I forgot to add the redirection, the example is the same as in the website but I'm still receiving the error.

Comment: Did you added your domain on the facebook developer settings? i edited my answer to show how to do that, i was using `http://localhost:8080` as my domain to test and it worked, you should give it a try

Comment: @DiegoLópez I did that, my fix was just changing the hello.js file I was using (I got it from the GitHub repo and is called hello.js) for the one they use in their website which is called hello.all.js and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: great! i'm glad you could work it out.

Answer (score 1):

You must first register as a [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) to get an Facebook Developer ID, then you can replace the facebook : XXXXXXXXXXX with your ID. Also you have to specify the return URL. eg.

```
hello.init({ 
    facebook : 355555184404909, //eg. Facebook ID
},{redirect_uri:'http://yourDomain/return.html'});
```

you can also register yourself as a developer on these networks [Windows Live](http://dev.live.com/) or [Google+](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/#:access)

EDIT: Added how to register your domain to a the Facebook Website Platform

You must register your domain on Facebook Developer Settings to allow the library to redirect to your domain
[image: Website platform configuration]
Just enter your domain `http://yourDomain` on the "Website URL" field.

Comment: I sincerely hope the OP did that, and it's not the root cause of the problem. Nonetheless, a much needed sanity check.

Comment: So do you think is a problem with the library itself?

Comment: nope the library is fine, i replicated your exception and fixed it by using a real facebook developer id, try the code above with your developer id (instead of using 355555184404909 or XXXXXXXXXXXXX)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an app as a Facebook Developer (https://developers.facebook.com/apps). You can then retrieve your Facebook App's Client ID.

As shown in hello's official website:

```
hello.init({ 
    facebook : FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
},{redirect_uri:'redirect.html'});
```